# Simple coinflip terminal game won't update variable

Tags: python

I am trying to code a simple coinflip game with a gambling function. My issue is, whenever it runs, it doesn't update the `balance` variable. Any suggestions?

```
import random

balance = 10
win = "Congrats! You have won "
lose = "That's too bad, you lost this time! You now have "



start_game = False
while True:
    choice = input("Please use one of these commands 'flip', 'balance', or 'end game'. ")
    if choice == "flip":
        start_game = True
        break
    elif choice == "balance":
        print(balance)
    elif choice == "end game":
        break
    else:
        print("Please use one of the listed commands!")

if start_game == True:
    while True:
        result = random.randint(1,2)
        if result == 1:
            result = True
        elif result == 2:
            result = False    
        
        gamble_amount = input("How much would you like to flip? You have " + str(balance) + " coins. ")
        if str(gamble_amount) == "balance":
            print(balance)
        elif int(gamble_amount) <= int(balance) and result == True:
            int(gamble_amount) * 2
            int(balance) + int(gamble_amount)
            print(win + str(gamble_amount) + "!" + " You now have " + str(balance) + "!")
        elif int(gamble_amount) <= int(balance) and result == False:
            int(balance) - int(gamble_amount)
            print(lose + str(balance) + " coins!")
```

Comment: Whenever you want to change the value of a variable such as `balance`, you need to call `balance = new_value`, whatever `new_value` is. I've noticed that apart from the initial `balance = 10`, you never actually update the value of `balance`.

Comment: There's a few places where you just do a formula, but don't actually assign the results to a variable, so... nothing happens. For instance: `int(gamble_amount) * 2` and `int(gamble_amount) * 2`. Instead I'm guessing you probably want that to be: `balance = balance + (gamble_amount * 2)`. And then in your `elif` `int(balance) - int(gamble_amount)` should be `balance = int(balance) - int(gamble_amount)`.

Comment: `int(gamble_amount) * 2`,`int(balance) + int(gamble_amount)` and `int(balance) - int(gamble_amount)` doesn't do anything useful. You're just calculating a value, but never using it or storing it, you're just calculating it and throwing the result away.

Comment: Also, all those castings are unnecessary. You don't need to do `str(gamble_amount)` because it's already a string, and you don't need to do `int(balance)` because it's already an integer.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. @JNevill That definitely makes sense now, and I can see where my issue is and understand how to fix it.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman My reasoning for the castings is I kept getting errors saying that I couldn't concatenate strings with integers and integers with strings in some of the calculations so it was just a sloppy temporary solution to that problem, but I'll definitely look more into it and try to clean it up with your suggestion, thank you!